# Is it possible to join an overlay network with different os?

Tags: docker, overlay, docker-swarm, docker-network

I am having trouble to join an overlay network that spans multiple hosts.
I have created a swarm with a linux centos node as the manager and a windows worker following this guide: https://santanderglobaltech.com/en/using-docker-overlay-networks-configuration-guide/

However, when trying to join the overlay network, the command `docker run -it --name alpine1 --network my-net alpine` fails with the error `Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded.`

The manager node logs has the following error `Was able to connect to 055a111d1edb but other probes failed`

- The required ports are all opened
- The hosts have the same docker engine version (20.10.5)
- The nodes are all Availability:active and Status:Ready
- Both the hosts show up when I run `docker node ls` on the manager node

I've tried to disable firewall on both hosts, same result.

Is it possible to join the overlay network, if so, what am I missing?